# Claim: The Euler's totient function is unique with the following property

Tags: solution-verification, totient-function, dirichlet-convolution

In this post, I had an idea that

$$\varphi(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d \cdot \mu(\frac{n}{d})$$

has this property, where $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Let $\star$ be the Dirichlet convolution of functions $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$(f \star g)(n) = \sum_{ab = n} f(a)g(b) = \sum_{d \mid n} f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$$

If $\text{Id}$ is the identity function (i.e., $\text{Id}(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$), $1$ is the "$1$" function (i.e., $1(n) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$), and $\varphi$ to be the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), is the Euler's totient function the unique function that satisfy $\text{Id} = 1 \star \varphi$?

Indeed! I made a proof.

**Proof:**

Notice, first, that for any two functions $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$

$$ f = 1 \star g \iff g = f \star \mu$$

and $$\varepsilon = 1 \star \mu$$

where $\varepsilon(n) = \lfloor \frac{1}{n} \rfloor$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Denote $D := \{f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C} \, \mid \, f(1) \ne 0\}$. Then $(D, \star)$ is an abelian group. The identity in $D$ is $\varepsilon$. Also, each functions $f$ have *Dirichlet inverses* iff $f(1) \ne 0$. That is, $(\forall f \in D)(\exists! g \in D)$ such that
$$f \star g = \varepsilon \iff f(1) \ne 0$$.

Notice, $\varphi \in D$. So, if $\text{Id} = 1 \star f = 1 \star \varphi$, then,

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{Id} = 1 \star f = 1 \star \varphi &&\iff &\mu \star 1 \star f = \mu \star 1 \star \varphi\\
&&\iff &(\mu \star 1) \star f = (\mu \star 1) \star \varphi\\
&&\iff &\varepsilon \star f = \varepsilon \star \varphi\\
&&\iff &f = \varphi &\square
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

**Question**

Is this proof correct and valid?

### Edit

I searched this in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution).

Comment: Looks good (and standard) to me.

Comment: In general,  $f\star 1= g,$ iff $g\star \mu=f.$ This is because $\star$ is a commutative and associative operation, with identity $I$ defined as $I(1)=1, I(n)=0$ for $n >1.$ Finally $1\star \mu=I.$

Comment: The entire work of the argument is to show that $f$ has a Dirichlet inverse iff $f(1) \neq 0$ and you've claimed this without proving it; this is actually what you need to show here.